# How to customize ubiquity and include it in a ubuntu remix

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity, livedvd

Hi i recently installed Ubuntu and customized it to the OS of my needs and using the linux live scripts from the http://www.linux-live.org/ website i created my own version of linux distro off my current installation and thus i was able to create my live iso. But i want the iso to be installed on the hard drives of other computers so i want to create a installer wizard for my remix. So how can i tweak ubiquity and include it in the live iso image.

Also please tell me that if i am able to use ubiquity(or some better alternatives) on non-ubuntu isos. ( In case i create a non-ubuntu live iso that i want to be installable)...

Comment: If I understand properly, the created remix ISO file doesn't contain any installer; So this question should be rephrased to "How to include Ubiquity installer in Ubuntu remix Live ISO?" instead. Or, did you mean "How to customize Ubiquity installer?" These are two different things.